# How to get the label builder not to force downcase everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I'm using the label helper in a form contex, the label is getting downcased. Can I change this behavior?

example:

produce: "Things are getting big" but I want "Things Are Getting Big"

using rails 2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/label). First parameter for the `label` is the name of the field it references, not label's text. If there is no text provided, it uses field's name (localized/humanized)

Your label code produces

```
<label for="form_record_Things Are Getting Big">Things are getting big</label>
```

And you possibly need

```
<label for="form_record_field_name">Things are getting big</label>
```

You can do that with:

```
<%= f.label :field_name, "Things Are Getting Big" %>
```